# Is there possible execute function while fabric SUDO is running

Tags: python, fabric

I am executing a rsync command and getting the output in realtime with stdout.

My problem is that I need to manipulate this output while my command is running.

My old code worked with subprocess like this:

```
cmd = 'rsync -rc --delete --progress %s %s' % (path, PATH_LOCAL_STORAGE)
with io.open("%s%s" % (TEMP_LOCAL, filename), 'wb') as writer:
        process = sudo(cmd, stdout=writer, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
        while process.poll() is None:
            doWhatIWant()
            time.sleep(5)
```

So my doWhatIWant was executed each 5 seconds while my code rsync command were running.

Now I need to use Fabric Sudo instead of subprocess. I already tried to use @Parallel and @Task but without sucess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've archived this using Threads.

```
def RunMyCodeAsync(writer):
    sudo(cmd, stdout=writer, shell=True)

def DoMyCopy():
    with io.open('file.txt', 'wb') as writer:
        thread = threading.Thread(
            name='RunMyCodeAsync', 
            targed=RunMyCodeAsync, 
            args(writer,)) # args must have the comma ','
        thread.start()
        while thread.is_alive():
            DoWhatIWant()
            time.sleep(5) # Run each 5 seconds
```